# SQL IMPALA convert YYYY-QQ to YYYYMM integer

Tags: sql, date, type-conversion

My current variable is date (string) in format YYYY-QQ (quarter) e.g, 2017-Q2

I would like to select in the same query, another variable, converted to `YYYYMM` format e.g, 201706 as an integer.

The transformation for quarters to months goes as follows:

```
Q1 -> 03, Q2 -> 06, Q3 -> 09, Q4 -> 12
```

Code:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (newdate...)
FROM 
    {table}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If it's stored as a string, it's **NOT** a date.

Comment: Yes it is a string